# Kafka Streams - Serdes for Custom Objects

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm pretty new to Kafka Streams and found overall the API is confusing and documentation not easy to follow. I'm writing a simple streams app like this:

1. Input stream: key(String)->userID, value(String)->a user's transaction record JSON string.
2. Topology: aggregate the above input and generate a KTable<String, UserAccountBalance>. Key is userId, value is a custom object updated as the aggregation goes.

   ```
    final KStream<String, String> transactionsInput = streamsBuilder.stream("bank-balance-input-topic");
    final KTable<String, UserBankBalance> table =
            transactionsInput.groupBy((key, value) -> key)
                             .aggregate(() -> new UserBankBalance("dummyUserId", 0, "1866-12-23T17:47:37Z"),
                                        (userName, transactionRecordStr, userBankBalance) -> {
                                            // Code does the following:
                                            //   1. Deserialize the transactionRecordStr
                                            //   2. Update the UserBankBalance object.
                                            //   return userBankBalance;
                                        });
   ```

(Default key,value serdes configured to be String)
However, when running some sanity tests, I got String serializer not compatible with the UserBankBalance object.

1. Why are Serdes required for operations like mapValues, groupByKey, aggregate?

   My understanding:

   - Streams library need to materialize the object using the default serdes to update internal state?
   - If repartition happens, the key, value needs to be serialized and stored back to the internal partition for further processing?
   - Given the above, even if we just create the `KTable<String,UserBankBalance>` as in-memory representation, the Serdes is still required.

   I've read the official doc and API doc, just couldn't find any good clarification.
2. Why Kafka Stream's library doesn't provide a default `ObjectMapperSerdes` which utilize the Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (Like [this official example](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java#L83))? I imagine lots of users would have similar use cases and there would be duplicate efforts for the library users to do so.

References:

- [Architecture](https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/architecture)
- [DATA TYPES AND SERIALIZATION](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are Serdes required for operations

Kafka stores bytes. Streams API doesn't pass objects from one operation to the other, it uses Kafka as a message bus. It needs to serialize any object to bytes to send over the network.

If you are working with JSON, then Kafka Streams [already has a built-in way to create a JSONSerde](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewUntypedDemo.java#L70-L72); there doesn't need to be an `ObjectMapper` one since you can use `Serdes.serdeFrom` static method. (Also, it would create a dependency on `connect-json` module and bloat the `kafka-streams` classpath).

Alternatively, Spring-Kafka also has [`JsonSerde`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerde.html). And Confluent maintains `AvroSerde`, `ProtobufSerde`, etc. to use with classes generated from those tools.

> got String serializer not compatible with the UserBankBalance object

You need to use some combination of [`Grouped`, `Materialized`, `Consumed`, or `Produced`](https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/package-summary.html) classes with each operation to override the default topology serde.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful.

> 'It needs to serialize any object to bytes to send over the network.' 
Do you happen to know any documentation explaining this the expected behavior? I just feel this is not super efficient, so want to confirm further.

Comment: This is basic concept of serialization and TCP networking, nothing Kafka related

Comment: I'm asking about the part where streams library don't just pass object among operations, if it passes the serialized (key, val) pairs to the brokers every time, then it's a big IO overhead. Doesn't this [map](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java#L214) operation directly convert the string key to the object without specifying the key serdes?

Comment: Stateless operations such as `map` or `forEach` don't need network requests, no. But the JVM still needs to process the data as bytes. Kafka's serializers use generics, as well, so you need to give explicit type information on the operations.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I missed this. So for stateful operations, the streams library persists the state to a local state store (e.g. each aggregation result for a key will be recorded) and this is backed by a Kafka change log partition for fault tolerance (each aggregation result for a key will be streamed back to Kafka), thus Serdes are requied. Helpful video: https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/stateful-operations/